# What does a negative drive space mean in Get-PSDrive?

Tags: powershell

`Get-PSDrive` returns a negative number for the used disk space.

```
PS C:\Users\thomas> Get-PSDrive

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                               ---------------                                                                                       
[...]                                                                                     
H                -782,81       1172,81 FileSystem    \\server\fileexchange   
[...]
```

Does that have a special meaning?

I looked up the help (`Get-Help 'Get-PSDrive' -ShowWindow`) but I could not find an explanation.

I am aware of a [similar issue regarding Get-Process](https://tfl09.blogspot.de/2008/12/get-process-produces-negative-numbers.html) where the reason is an overflow. Is it the same here? Is there a workaround?

As requested by @Andrew Morton in the comments:

```
PS C:\Users\thomas> [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() | Format-Table

Name DriveType DriveFormat IsReady AvailableFreeSpace TotalFreeSpace    TotalSize RootDirectory VolumeLabel
---- --------- ----------- ------- ------------------ --------------    --------- ------------- -----------
[...]
H:\    Network NTFS           True       223231537152  1253398024192 418759311360 H:\           Data       
[...]
```

I read this as 223 GB available free space, 1253 GB total free space and 418 GB total size. If I simply subtract the total free space from the total size, I get -835 GB, which matches the Powershell value (considering that some data has been added in the meanwhile).

Here's what Windows Explorer says:

[image: Screenshot of the drive in Windows Explorer]

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I've added the information in the question.

Comment: As it is a network drive, perhaps there is something like a quota which is confusing things. Can you check the same drive statistics on the server itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your drive exceeds a supported by the function you used value.

Example: a 3TB drive that you try to read with a function supporting only 2TB will result in the following:

The 3TB drive is actually 2.72 TB in usable space. Because it exceeds 2TB, the rest of the space will how as negative value (so your result will be -0.72TB).

If you exceed 4TB, it will be a positive value again and if you exceed 6TB it will again be negative. This repeats forever, but the cause is that the function you used is limited at 2TB.

This is valid for any function reading drive space and the limitations can exist at other values too (like 4GB for older functions that try to read NTFS large files).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this described in some "official" documentation?

Comment: Yes, I found it at a point. It's documented for multiple situations and it's valid also for many other limited functions. An exception seems to be Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController, which will only show 2GB of the total RAM no matter how much over 2GB you have and there is no 64-bit equivalent.